# bootstrap 4 my slider is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

**my bootstrap 4 slider is not working properly!**
its show only 1 mage rather then 3

```html
<title>
    Welcome - Maqbool Solutions
</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon_Y13_5.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/function.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font/css/font-awesome.css">
<style>
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
        transform: translateX(33.33%);
    }

    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
        transform: translateX(-33.33%)
    }

    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
</style>
<script>
    $('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 10000
    })

    $('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function() {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        if (next.next().length > 0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        } else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
</script> </head>
```

```html
<div class="container text-center my-3">
    <h2>Bootstrap 4 Multiple Item Carousel</h2>
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=1">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=2">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=3">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=4">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=5">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=6">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Advances one slide at a time</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap javascript file

Answer (score 1):

Just include the bootstrap.js file.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4bajqypm/